# Returning malloc'd structs gives segfault and different address

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

Im developing a library that deals with certain network connections in C, and my plan was for the init function to return a struct containing all relevant data for the connection that the caller will then pass to any of the library functions. I also want the contents of the struct to be accessible to the caller.

**Here is my init (library) code**

```c
//here is the struct
typedef struct {
  SSL_CTX* ctx;
  SSL* ssl;
  int socket;
  int usingSSL;
} twitch_connection;


struct twitch_connection* twlibc_init(int usingSSL){ //returns a pointer to a struct that has to be freed
  twitch_connection *temp;
  temp = malloc(sizeof(twitch_connection)); //creates the address for the struct
  struct sockaddr_in twitchaddr;
  ...
  if(usingSSL == 0){
    //not using SSL
    temp->ctx = NULL;
    temp->ssl = NULL;
  }else {
    //using SSL
    temp->ctx = ctx; //how I assign values to the struct
    temp->ssl = ssl;
  }
  
  temp->socket = twitchsock;

  return temp; //returns the struct back to caller
}
```

**here is the code from my demo**

```c
int main(){
  
  twitch_connection* twlibc = twlibc_init(1);

  
  printf("address of struct from main of callers code is: %p\n", twlibc);
}
```

However when I printf the addresses of the struct I get different results when printing from different areas in the code:

```sh
address of struct from inside init function: 0x56299befd260
address of struct from main of callers code is: 0xffffffff9befd260
```

and if I try to printf a member of the struct from the main function I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: It's close but the code shown is not complete. We need to see **exact** code that can reproduce the problem. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You showed us some of your code which is nice, but you showed us only the parts that work.  Show us the code that fails.

Comment: Where are the **warnings**? Are you paying attention to any of them? Compile with `-Wall -Werror`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `twitch_connection* twlibc = twlibc_init(1);`

Since `twlibc_init` was not declared at this point, C assumes that the return value is an int, so the above is equivalent to `twlibc = (twitch_connection*)(int)twlibc_init(1);`.

On a 64-bit platform with 32-bit `int` type this will truncate `0x56299befd260` to a 32-bit integer `0x9befd260` then sign-extend it to a 64-bit pointer `0xffffffff9befd260`.

The solution is to declare the function `struct twitch_connection* twlibc_init(int usingSSL);` in the main file or, even better, move the declarations to a common header included in both places.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The sign-extension when casting an `int` to a pointer is implementation dependent and not guaranteed by the C standard, so another compiler might have printed `0x9befd260` instead or, indeed, anything. From the cppreference [C cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) page:

> *Any integer can be cast to any pointer type. Except for the null pointer constants such as NULL (which doesn't need a cast), the result is implementation-defined, may not be correctly aligned, may not point to an object of the referenced type, and may be a trap representation.*

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working. Turns out I already had it declared in the header function that I used but it was a remnant from my old code when this method returned an int (just the socket). `int twlibc_init(int usingSSL);`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's sound advice, twice so when developing a library (presumably) for others' use.